# dream weaver is not detecting database

Tags: mysql, database, dreamweaver

THIS is my login file

```
<?php //login.php

$hn= 'localhost';
$db ='publications';
$un = 'root';
$pw= '';
?>
```

THIS is my connection File

```
<?    php
require_once "login.php";
$conn =new mysqli($hn,$un,$pw,$db,'3306');
if($conn->connect_error)die(  "cant connect");

else
echo "connected successfully";
?>
```

i am able to connected successfully when i use DSV PHP editor to run the code .
However when i run same code in Dreamweaver it says

```
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database 'publications' in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\add_data.php on line 3
cant connect
```

Comment: Have you got such database?

Comment: no its just for testing purpose.

Comment: Then how do you expect to connect to non-existent database?

Comment: Sorry i mean to say the i kept password and username  so easy just for testing purpose.

However i have database of this name.. and i can access it with any other code editor with same line of codes .
But not with Dreamweaver CC.

I dont know why Dreamweaver is creating such issue
Plz help